# Distribution Function of KPSS Variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, brownian-motion

Assume that I have a vector called $X_j$, then I have a test statistic called $T_N$ as follows

$$T_N=\frac{1}{s^2_N N^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(\sum_{j=1}^{k}(X_j-\bar{X}_N))^2$$

where $s^2_N=[N-1]^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{N}(X_j-\bar{X}_N)^2$. The weak convergence of random variable $T_N$ is $U_{\text{KPSS}}$ i.e. $T_N \Rightarrow U_{\text{KPSS}}$ such that $U_{\text{KPSS}}=\int_{0}^{1}(W^0(t))^2dt$ where $W^0(t)$ is a Brownian bridge denoted by $W(t)-tW(1)$.

The distribution function of the random variable $U_{\text{KPSS}}$ has a series expansion and the random variable $U_{\text{KPSS}}$ itself has the following series form $U_{\text{KPSS}}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{Y_j^2}{j^2}$ where $Y_j \sim_{i.i.d.}N(0,1)$. Then my question is assuming $T_N=0.04$ similar to the following example in R, how can I find the value of the distribution function particularly in R as $U_{KPSS}$ has a series form? Note that I am not looking for $U$, but its distribution function. My actual $T_N$ is a very large vector. So, it is important to find a reasonable way to handle this probelm in R. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

```
> X
 [1]  0.374537430 -0.390749880  1.333877600  0.603881350 -0.990818460 -0.640132810  0.193950360  0.278389730
 [9] -1.231008200  0.272478930  0.186832450  1.775870900 -1.764572600 -0.604860080  1.093131800 -0.282344130
[17]  0.006673559 -0.156819780  0.222386980  0.850713160
> Xbar <- mean(X)
> s2 <- var(X)
> N <- length(X)
> 
> T_Ninit <- rep(NA,N)
> for(k in 1:N){
+   T_Ninit[k] <- sum(X[1:k]-Xbar)
+ }
> 
> T_N <- (s2*N^2)^(-1)*sum((T_Ninit)^2)
```

Comment: Either simulate the Brownian bridge and compute the pathwise integral, or simulate the sum (for replace $\infty$ by a large $n$).

Comment: I have tried this; it does not work. I imagine it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? This is how KPSS obtained their critical values. In any case, why not just use the KPSS critical values?

Comment: U_{KPSS} is a series; for example, if it was (1/pi^2) \sum_j(Y^2/j^2) not Y_j, then it was clear how to simulate the series and find critical values. The fact is that we have Y_j. So, then if T_N=0.04, what suppose to be its critical value? Hope it makes sense. If you have a clear idea, please write the code and provide a clear answer. Thank you!

Comment: Look at Kwiatkowski D, Phillips PC, Schmidt P, Shin Y (KPSS) 1992 Journal of Econometrics "Testing the null hypothesis of stationarity against the alternative of a unit root".  It says to simulate the Brownian bridge and then the integral. Actually they already did the simulation and provided critical values in their Table 1.

Comment: Actually, I have tried that and I have read the paper of KPSS(1992). Actually the main critical values for KPSS test are in Tables of 3 and 4 of Kiefer (1959) and the paper is for 1960's and has columns of B_i's and quite unclear how to use it. The paper title is: "K-Sample Analogues of the Kolmogrov-Smirnov and Cramer-V Mises Tests" and I do not think you have even read the paper. Please also provide more polite comments when you do not know!